# List of dictionaries from CSV file

Tags: c#, list, linq, dictionary

I have csv file like:

```
col1;col2
val1;val2
val3;val4
```

I would like to create list of dictionaries which will be like:

```
[0] k:col1, v:val1
    k:col2, v:val2
[1] k:col1, v:val3
    k:col2, v:val4
```

Or maybe you know a better way? I have to iterate over this list and the number of fields (columns) is variable.

Comment: If you would describe to us what you would like to achieve and what you've tried so far, how much data there is... we may be able to give you an expertize on what you could do :)

Comment: I would like to iterate over this CSV file, but don't know how to do this. I don't want to create class for row, becasue the file will have a different number of columns in future. I need a generic and FAST solution.

Comment: Why a dictionary? You can use a `List<string[]>` or a `DataTable`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The solution

Here's a simplified method to return you what you want. I've commented every step to explain the approach. The steps in and of themselves should be easy enough to understand.

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines("c:\\myfile.csv");

//1. Read all headers
string[] columnHeaders = lines[0].Split(';');

//2. Instantiate your end result variable.
List<Dictionary<string, string>> linesAsDictionaries = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();

//3. Process all lines (except the header row!)
foreach(var line in lines.Skip(1))
{
    //3.1 Instantiate the resulting dictionary
    var newDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    //3.2 Split the data
    var cells = line.Split(';');

    //3.3 Add an entry for each retrieved header.
    for (int i = 0; i < columnHeaders.Length; i++)
    {
        newDict.Add(columnHeaders[i], cells[i]);
    }

    //3.4 Add the dictionary to the resulting list
    linesAsDictionaries.Add(newDict);
}

return linesAsDictionaries;
```

---

### Some caveats

1. You explicitly asked for a `List<Dictionary<string, string>>`, and that is the answer I've provided. You'd be much better off with a data class (whose properties match the columns that you expect to find), if it fits your current scenario.
2. You might want to add a few null-checks and try-catches. I've omitted them from my example for brevity's sake.
3. Notice that my example only parses the cells based on **how many headers** were found. If some of your data rows have more cells than there are headers, those cells will be ignored.
4. There are LINQ ways to solve this in a similar fashion, but I opted for the `foreach` because it's easier to read, and I think that understanding the **intention of the algorithm** is more important.
5. If you're going to be parsing a massive CSV file, you might be better off by using a `StreamReader` to read the file line by line (so you don't have to take everything into memory all at once). `File.ReadAllLines()` works sufficiently for "normal" sized CSV files.
6. You will encounter an `IndexOutOfRange` exception if any of the rows has **less data cells** than there are headers (in other words, it happens when `cells.Length < columnHeaders.Length`). If you encounter this, then you need to add an extra check to make sure that you only assign values if both a header **and** a cell value exists. But I've omitted it from the example as it would obfuscate the (relatively simple) underlying algorithm.
7. If you encounter **duplicate headers**, then you will encounter an exception (this is somewhat by intention, as opposed to having the second column overwrite the first column's value in the dictionary without making a fuss). If this is an issue that you need to avoid, figure out what you want done and add the necessary code.

   - Should a second (duplicate) header be ignored, while the rest of the file is still parsed as normal?
   - Do you want to store both values? (this would mean moving away from the `Dictionary<string,string>` approach)
   - Do you want to stop parsing the file and throw an exception?
   - ...

Comment: Thanks for your solution! For my needs is enough :)
PS. You skipped 'linesAsDictionaries.Add(newDict);' at the end of the 'foreach' loop ;)

Comment: @cs9112: Good catch! When constructing similar solutions, that's the line I always tend to forget ;) I think it's because the LINQ-equivalent doesn't need explicit addition anymore, that I've lost the habit of writing one.